# Inserting values in sqlite 3 but appearing as column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Im using inputs from **SQLite3** in python 3.5 to add user information to a data base. However once i obtain the data and insert into the database, rather than inserting the data into the columns it tells me there is no column.
The error I get is as follows:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "C:\Users\Luke_2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1549, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Luke_2\Desktop\Computing\Coursework\live\current.py", line
>   303, in details
>       cur_user.execute("INSERT INTO LogIn(Email,Password) VALUES("+user+","+passw+")") sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:
>   a

And the function in my code doing this is as follows:

```
def details():
    user = email_sign.get()
    user1 = email1_sign.get()
    passw = password_sign.get()
    password1 = password1_sign.get()
    if user == user1 and passw == password1:
        cur_user.execute("INSERT INTO LogIn(Email,Password) VALUES("+user+","+passw+")")
        conn_user.commit()

    else:
        print("please try again")
```

Comment: Try this line: cur_user.execute("INSERT INTO LogIn(Email,Password) VALUES('%s','%s')" % (user, passw))

Comment: @DenisV thats perfect, thank you

Comment: @DenisV it is far from perfect because still subject to SQL injection...

Comment: Duplicate question, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142531/sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-column

Comment: @SergeBallesta I did not said that it's the best way, I just gave the solution to his problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the request that you actually execute has no quotes around the values, so the names are interpreted as column names but the SQL engine. If you pass `a` and `b` respectively you will execute

```
INSERT INTO LogIn(Email,Password) VALUES(a,b)
```

when what is required is

```
INSERT INTO LogIn(Email,Password) VALUES('a','b')
```

But you should **never** to that! Building requests that way but *hardcoding* parameters in the request has been the cause of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problems for decades.

The correct way is to build a parameterized request:

```
cur_user.execute("INSERT INTO LogIn(Email,Password) VALUES(?,?)", (user, password))
```

simpler, smarter and immune to SQL injection...