# confusing SQLite3 Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Ive made a database in python with SQLite3 and im trying to add some data but im currently getting the error `You did not supply a value for binding 1.`. Ive made the exact same database (with different values) before but did not get this error, what am i doing wrong here?

This is the database with the error:

```
def Add_User_Data(self):
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (:ID, :FirstName, :Surname, :DOB, :Age, :Gender)",
                     {'ID: ': self.AddEmployee.ID.get(), 'FirstName: ':self.AddEmployee.FirstName.get(), 'Surname: ':self.AddEmployee.Surname.get(),
                     'DOB: ':self.AddEmployee.DOB.get(), 'Age: ':self.AddEmployee.Age.get(), 'Gender: ':self.AddEmployee.Gender.get()})


        self.conn.commit()
```

And this is the old one that did not get an error.

```
def addEmployees(self):
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (:FirstName, :Surname, :Age, :Postcode, :Wage, :Email, :Hours)",
                     {'FirstName': 'aa', 'Surname':"Jan" , 'Age':"21" ,
                     'Postcode':"UB5 7T3" , 'Wage':"1220000" , 'Email':"s@gmail.com" , 'Hours':"230"})

        self.conn.commit()
```

-------------------------------------------------------- Answer ----------------------------------------------------------------

So i fixed the problem by changing the layout to this and it worked:

```
self.params = (self.AddEmployee.ID.get(), self.AddEmployee.FirstName.get(), self.AddEmployee.Surname.get(),
        self.AddEmployee.DOB.get(), self.AddEmployee.Age.get(), self.AddEmployee.Gender.get())

        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )", self.params)

        self.conn.commit()
```

I found the solution at: [sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142531/sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-column)

Thank you to everyone that has replied and tried to help!

Comment: This is a typographic error. Simply, remove the space and colon in parameter dictionary keys. Also, IDs are usually auto-generated.

Comment: @Parfait just tried it, got the same error. :/

Comment: Yeah, i changed it just like you said, I also just printed `self.AddEmployee.ID.get()` as an test and got the right data. Im starting to think its not even my fault this error is occurring lol

Comment: @Parfait It was just `ID` but i just changed it to `IDNumber` which still gave me the same annoying error :(

Comment: @Parfait check out my code if you want. - https://github.com/Sharjeel50/Database-System/blob/master/Database-System.py

Comment: @YouKnowMe...you CAN use named parameters for SQLite. Did you remove the colon inside the keys as my very first comment indicated (not just the space)? For dictionaries, you do no need a colon *outside* to separate keys and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers as [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) show, the Python sqlite3 DB-API supports both *qmark* and *named* styles for parameterization. OP resolved issue using *qmark* style. However, OP's original attempt can indeed work with proper dictionary key assignment where the dictionary keys correspond exactly to the named parameters.

Specifically, the following dictionary will fail to bind to named parameters (`:ID, :FirstName, :Surname, ...`) due to the colon and space within dictionary keys:

```
{'ID: ': self.AddEmployee.ID.get(), 
 'FirstName: ':self.AddEmployee.FirstName.get(), 
 'Surname: ':self.AddEmployee.Surname.get(),
 'DOB: ':self.AddEmployee.DOB.get(), 
 'Age: ':self.AddEmployee.Age.get(), 
 'Gender: ':self.AddEmployee.Gender.get()}
```

However, the following should work for the same prepared SQL statement:

```
{'ID': self.AddEmployee.ID.get(), 
 'FirstName': self.AddEmployee.FirstName.get(), 
 'Surname': self.AddEmployee.Surname.get(),
 'DOB': self.AddEmployee.DOB.get(), 
 'Age': self.AddEmployee.Age.get(), 
 'Gender': self.AddEmployee.Gender.get()}
```

Altogether, for cursor call:

```
self.sql = "INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (:ID, :FirstName, :Surname, :DOB, :Age, :Gender)"

self.qparams = {'ID': self.AddEmployee.ID.get(), 
                'FirstName': self.AddEmployee.FirstName.get(), 
                'Surname': self.AddEmployee.Surname.get(),
                'DOB': self.AddEmployee.DOB.get(), 
                'Age': self.AddEmployee.Age.get(), 
                'Gender': self.AddEmployee.Gender.get()}

self.c.execute(self.sql, self.qparams)
self.conn.commit()
```